# Proving minimum polynomial equals characteristic polynomial in a cyclic vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $\mathbb{F}$ and $T:V \rightarrow V$ be a linear map.
Let $v \in V$ be such that $\left \{ v,T(v),T^{2}(v)... \right \}$ spans $V$.

I have proved that $B=\left \{ v,T(v),T^{2}(v)...,T^{k-1}(v) \right \}$ is a basis for $V$ for some $k \geq 1$. But, I am now asked to prove **without using the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem** that the minimum polynomial equals the characteristic polynomial.

I first let $A$ be the matrix of $T$ with respect to $B$, so for some non-zero $\alpha_{0},...,\alpha_{k-1} \in \mathbb{F}$ we have:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
 0 &  &  &  &  &\alpha_{0}\\ 
 1& 0 &  &  &  & .\\ 
 & . & . &  &  &.\\ 
 &  & . & . &  & .\\ 
 &  &  &  & 0 & \alpha_{k-2}\\ 
 &  &  &  & 1 & \alpha_{k-1}
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$\Rightarrow det(A-\lambda I)=\begin{vmatrix}
 -\lambda &  &  &  &  &\alpha_{0}\\ 
 1& -\lambda &  &  &  & .\\ 
 & . & . &  &  &.\\ 
 &  & . & . &  & .\\ 
 &  &  &  & -\lambda & \alpha_{k-2}\\ 
 &  &  &  & 1 & \alpha_{k-1}-\lambda
\end{vmatrix}$$

And I want to expand by minors along the last column, but I'm having real difficulty getting anything that seems useful from that. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Instead you could expand along the first row. Then there are two terms, the first corresponding to $-\lambda$ the minor is by induction the polynomial for $a_2, \ldots , a_{k-1}$. The minor for $a_0$ is a lower triangular matrix with diagonals $1$, put it together and you get the desired result.