# Cyclic vectors - minimum and annihilating polynomial must be equal

Tags: linear-algebra

> An element $v$ of $V$ is called cyclic for $T$ if $V$ is spanned by its subset $\left\{v, T(v), T^2(v), \ldots\right\}$. Show that if $v$ is cyclic for $T$ then there is some $k \geqslant 1$ such that
> $$
> B=\left\{v, T(v), T^2(v), \ldots, T^{k-1}(v)\right\}
> $$
> is a linearly independent subset of $V$ and $T^k(v)$ lies in the span of $B$. Deduce that $B$ is a basis for $V$ and hence that $k=n$.
>
> By considering the matrix of $T$ with respect to the basis $B$, prove (without using the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem) that $m_T=\chi_T$.
> Now let $V=\mathbb{R}^3$ and define $T_1: V \rightarrow V$ and $T_2: V \rightarrow V$ by $T_j(v)=A_j v$ for $j=1,2$ where
> $$
> A_1=\left(\begin{array}{lll}
> 1 & 1 & 0 \\
> 0 & 1 & 1 \\
> 0 & 0 & 1
> \end{array}\right) \text { and } A_2=\left(\begin{array}{lll}
> 1 & 1 & 0 \\
> 0 & 1 & 0 \\
> 0 & 0 & 1
> \end{array}\right)
> $$
> Is there an element $v \in \mathbb{R}^3$ which is cyclic for $T_1$ ? Is there an element $v \in \mathbb{R}^3$ which is cyclic for $T_2$ ? Justify your answers briefly.

I've finished showing that B is a basis for V. I'm now doing the same part of the question as this OP: [Proving minimum polynomial equals characteristic polynomial in a cyclic vector space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/803965/proving-minimum-polynomial-equals-characteristic-polynomial-in-a-cyclic-vector-s)

But I'm not sure how they got the matrix of T with respect to basis B? Please can someone provide me with some help if possible?

Also, for the last part, I think that there is such an element for $A_1$ since the minimal polynomial is equal to the annihilating polynomial (so using the above part). However, this is not true for $A_2$ so no such element exists. Is this the correct approach? Thanks.

Comment: Let $v_j = T^{j-1}(v)$ denote the elements of $B$. You can get the first $k-1$ columns using the fact that $T(v_{j}) = v_{j+1}$ for $j = 1,\dots,k-1$. For the last column, use the minimal polynomial of $T$ to relate $T^k(v)$ to $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_k$.